# Is it possible to gradually zoom / resize the scene in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

I'm building a game using Swift and Sprite kit, and I want to implement a zoom mechanism kinda like Tiny Wings ( when you reach a certain location, the scene zooms out and let you see further away).

I tried self.size = CGSizeMake(newX, newY), and it just abruptly resized the scene. I want the resizing to happen gradually. How can I do that ?

Update: I found the the resizeing makes the  generated level to some weird location, I might be able to fix this, but  is there any zoom mechanism that  let the scene behave just the way it was ? (just zoom, and do nothing else)

Comment: Use the scale property.

Comment: thanks, it indeed works better than resize the scene

Answer (score 0):

Change the size in an animation closure, that you send to `UIView.animateWithDuration` with a duration. That will animate the changes.

Example:

```
let animations: () -> () = {
    self.size = CGRectMake(newX, newY)
}

UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: animations)
```

This will animate the change in size over 1 second.

Comment: I applied this, there's no error, but still no animation at all.

Comment: What's going wrong then? I can't do anything with no information

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. In the Update( ) method I figured out a way to make a small increment to the size in every new frame, which kinda works, but probably not an elegant solution.

Comment: Indeed, this is how one does an animation in iOS. Does it execute this code? It should work.

Comment: It works, but I finally find a better solution, add all of the nodes to a parent SKNode, and scale that SKNode, it works better than resize the scene.